# Files with long extensions unexpectedly deleted using command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

i am trying to delete some files using a batch file.. (winxp)

my problem is when i delete using a wildcard.. it is matching the 8.3 name  aswell as the long name.

eg:
file list

```
file1.py
file1.pyc
file2.pycstlongname
file2.pycstlongnamec
```

if i do a

```
Del *.pyc
```

it deletes everything but file1.py

becuase if i do a dir /X  all of teh 8.3 shortnames end with .PYC

Comment: This is why I got into the habit a long time ago of spelling DEL as DIR and looking at the results... but that doesn't help a BAT file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When you perform file management using
>   wildcards from the command prompt,
>   files with long extensions can be
>   unexpectedly displayed, copied, or
>   deleted.

You are right, it happens on my computer too, running fully-patched Windows XP SP3.

See the following Microsoft Knowledgebase Article for more information, and a registry change that will solve it.  This one goes all the way back to Windows NT 4.0:

Article ID: 164351 - Last Review: November 1, 2006 - Revision: 1.1
**[Command Prompt's Treatment of Long File Extensions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164351)**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164351

**UPDATE:**  This behavior also occurs in a test C# application I wrote.  The behavior is disturbing enough that I applied the registry fix to my computer, and it does work.

Comment: *sigh*..  yep.. that'd be right.. i'll test this later.

i will not help me too much, because i want to distribute the .bat file.. and i wont be able to set the registry on every machine.

Comment: You could always use the REG command in the .BAT file to test and adjust the key. It looks like it applies to the file system driver, so a reboot really would be required for it to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

Well, in your case you can probably use [`forfiles`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551(WS.10).aspx):

```
> forfiles /m *.pyc
"file1.pyc"
```

it does not adhere to cmd's wildcard expansion rules.

You can also enumerate all files and filter for extension afterwards:

```
> for %i in (*) do @if %~xi==.pyc @echo %i
file1.pyc
```

Both methods skip the files where only the .3 part of the extension matches.

So you can use either

```
forfiles /m *.pyc /c del @FILE
```

or

```
for %i in (*) do @if %~xi==.pyc @del "%i"
```

Admittedly, a little more complex than a simple `del *.pyc`, though.

**ETA:** Since someone was sceptical whether this would work, a little snippet from a cmd session on a Win XP SP 2 VM:

```
S:\Temp>for %i in (file1.py,file1.pyc,file2.pycstlongname,file2.pycstlongnamec) do @copy nul %i
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.

S:\Temp>dir /b
file1.py
file1.pyc
file2.pycstlongname
file2.pycstlongnamec

S:\Temp>del *.pyc

S:\Temp>dir /b
file1.py

S:\Temp>del *

S:\Temp>for %i in (file1.py,file1.pyc,file2.pycstlongname,file2.pycstlongnamec) do @copy nul %i
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.
        1 Datei(en) kopiert.

S:\Temp>for %i in (*) do @if %~xi==.pyc @del "%i"

S:\Temp>dir /b
file1.py
file2.pycstlongname
file2.pycstlongnamec
```

Nevermind the German messages, I hope it shows that above method does in fact work.

---

To explain a bit why it works, we can take a look at the command:

```
for %i in (*) do @if %~xi==.pyc @del "%i"
```

The first part is trivial. `for %i in (*)` simply enumerates all files in the current directory. We then check for the extension; `%~xi` expands to the full extension (not 8.3 stuff), so running above line will cause the following commands to be run:

```
if .py == .pyc del "file1.py"
if .pyc == .pyc del "file1.pyc"
if .pycstlongname == .pyc del "file2.pycstlongname"
if .pycstlongnamec == .pyc del "file2.pycstlongnamec"
```

I hope it is obvious why this works better than the globbing done by cmd which includes 8.3 names. No wildcards here, nothing to do wrong.

The `forfiles` variant does work on my Win 7 and Vista machines here. I can only guess but I strongly suspect, forfiles does not implement the same wildcard matching rules as cmd. Since we are on Windows, every program expands wildcards for itself. This is *not* done by the shell, unlike on UNIX systems. How exactly programs do this differs sometimes and apparently it does here, too.

Needless to say that I consider `forfiles`'s approach here a little more sensible as 8.3 names should die a horrible death sometime soon. Or at least I hope they do.

Comment: forfiles exists at least since Windows Vista, although I have seen it on some legacy XP machines as well so far. The for command dates back at least to NT 4.

Comment: Given the behavior of the OS using DEL from the command prompt AND FileInfo.Delete() from C# code, I am skeptical that this would actually work.

Comment: I elaborated a little and hopefully convinced you by now :-)

Comment: +1 for the explanation.  I can see clearly why this would work.